# Amazon Cognito Login

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

*TL;DR*

Why isn't there `authenticate` (or `login`) in the same way there is `SignUp` or `ChangePassword` in AWS Cognito/AWS Cognito Identity Provider?

--

I'm struggling to understand how to implement AWS Cognito into an API flow. I've researched this extensively and feel like the functionality is so obvious, that I must be misunderstanding something.

This API will serve Android, iOS and an SPA. I imagine the basic flow to go through my api, with an endpoint something like this:

```
/v1.0/authenticate/
```

It would accept a user/pwd, then the PHP on the server would do something like this:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$sdk = new Aws\Sdk([
    'region'   => 'us-east-1',
    'version'  => 'latest'
]);

$client = $sdk->createCognitoIdentity(['profile' => 'app-test-cognito']);

$result = $client->login([
    'ClientId' => '6p16oao60fvakje31lexabcmplgecliecd99ntid', 
    'Username' => $user, 
    'Password' => $pwd]);
```

And `$result` would be a json string something like

```
{
   "result": "success",
   "token": "<the token>"
}
```

And the `token` would be returned to the client, who would store it in localStorage/memory and return it on every other API call until it expired, using `Authorization: Bearer <token>`.  I think the token would be a JWT that I could test for expiration on each call without having to leave my API, would also include an immutable userId and that could be trusted by decrypting using a API-based secret or signature test.

But there is little or no indication that there is anything like this in existence except this recent blog post, using Javascript, that indicates there is a JS method called 'authenticateUser':

https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx2O14ZY8A5LFHT/Accessing-Your-User-Pools-using-the-Amazon-Cognito-Identity-SDK-for-JavaScript  (I found this link in this SO question: [What is the REST (or CLI) API for logging in to Amazon Cognito user pools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37941780/what-is-the-rest-or-cli-api-for-logging-in-to-amazon-cognito-user-pools), which is similar to mine, I will allow, but not a duplicate).

But, I went to their Github repo and [did a search for 'authenticateUser'](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=authenticateuser) and found no such method. I also [did the same search in the PHP repo.](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=authenticateUser) Nope.

BTW, this (below) is a real, working `Signup` so it seems (to me) that it would follow that such an easy authentication would work, too. What am I missing??

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$sdk = new Aws\Sdk([
    'region'   => 'us-east-1',
    'version'  => 'latest'
]);

$client = $sdk->createCognitoIdentityProvider(['profile' => 'app-test-cognito']);

$result = $client->signUp([
    'ClientId' => '6p16oao60fvakje31lexabcmplgecliecd99ntid', 
    'Username' => 'fakeexampleusername', 
    'Password' => 'a#--sldjf383af09aw3jJJJL', 
    'UserAttributes' => [
        [
         'Name' => 'email',
         'Value'=> 'me@example.com'
        ],
     ],
]); // based on pool settings, even sends out an email automatically.
```

Note: I also checked out Auth0, which seemed great but didn't have and SDK-login, either (you have to forward to their servers and use a form they provide...); Stormpath was out of the price range.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is not a simple "authenticate" API. The auth flow begins with an "InitiateAuth" call, and a series of RespondToAuthChallenge. When all of the challenges (example: MFA) are completed, only then will RespondToAuthChallenge return tokens.

The documentation describing this is here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-authentication-flow.html

Comment: I've seen this but I wasn't sure if it applied to my situation. So, it's helpful that you say it does. However, I'm not clear what goes in "srpA" and when I am responding to challenge, do I just echo back the challenge they originated with and why all this isn't written up in example code instead of a paragraph or two in the documentation. To me, this is the center of Identity and should be the most clear use-case.

Comment: @Hans your signup example was very useful. It helped me get started because I agree the documentation is very confusing. If you got the login it working please Edit your answer to update the relevant bits (for people who land on this question trying to find the same). By the way this link seems pretty helpful: https://sanderknape.com/2017/02/getting-started-with-aws-cognito/