# Is it possible to login to Amazon Cognito via REST API without using the SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm looking at AWS Cognito documentaion here
[Authentication with a User Pool](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authentication.html)

Actually I looked at many links in the documentation without finding clear information about this.

In AWS Cognito, I successfully created user pool, app client and integrated signup and login in Android and iOS using the platform provided SDK (amplify). But I want to do that directly from REST client, for testing purposes to generate user tokens. I want to submit the required credentials, username and password and get the user token as I do from the SDK.

I also tried [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53343689/773718) but it gives an error

```
{
    "__type": "NotAuthorizedException",
    "message": "Unable to verify secret hash for client 1034me0p4rkfm17oidu7mkunu5"
}
```

Is this is something possible and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just managed to get it done. There is a setting while you create an application client in Cognito console `Enable Client Secret`

To get that functionality to work, You need to create another App client with `Enable Client Secret` disabled. Then use the example mentioned [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53343689/773718)

Answer (score 0):

Using client secret is possible. But just redundant if you are doing this from a we will be using that to generate a secret hash.

Here's the step by step process to get this to work.

1. Note your app clients client id
2. Note your app clients secret
3. Note your user pool region
4. Get the username
5. Get the password
6. Make sure that USER_PASSWORD_AUTH is enabled for your client

Post below data to the following url https://cognito-idp.{{cognito region}}.amazonaws.com

```
{
    "AuthParameters": {
        "USERNAME": "{{username}}",
        "PASSWORD": "{{password}}",
        "SECRET_HASH": "{{secret hash}}"
    },
    "AuthFlow": "USER_PASSWORD_AUTH",
    "ClientId": "{{client id}}"
}
```

Add headers to the post request

X-Amz-Target: AWSCognitoIdentityProviderService.InitiateAuth

Content-Type: application/x-amz-json-1.1

The steps to create the secret hash are as follows

1. Create a hmac hash for the secret using sha256 algorithm
2. update the hash with the username
3. convert this to base64

Example code in node js

```
const { createHmac } = require('crypto');

createHash = function(username, clientid, secret) {
    const hasher = createHmac('sha256', secret);
    hasher.update(`${username}${clientid}`);
    const secretHash = hasher.digest('base64');
    console.log(secretHash);
    return secretHash;
}
```

As you can see from the code above, in order to generate the secret hash, you have to expose the secret in the code. That's why using a client with secret is pointless if you intend to complete the login on a browser page. It would help if you're running this logic from a server or a mobile app where the secret isn't exposed publicly.