# Manual Authentication with Amazon Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I know of two ways to authenticate as a user and obtain the `access token`, one is through the [Hosted UI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-app-integration.html) and another with [various provided SDKs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authentication.html).

What I'm looking for is an endpoint obtain the `access token` directly with user credentials.

```
POST https://that-special-endpoint.com/login
{
 username: "example@email.com",
 password: "Abc123456",
 ...client ID, etc.
}
```

I've searched for some time but could not find how to do this. Is this not possible due to some security concerns that I'm not aware of?

I did consider creating a Lambda API and make use of the Cognito SDK to cater for my use case but I'm not sure if it's advisable...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Similar question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53343689/12656244). You can access `https://cognito-idp.[region].amazonaws.com/` to call `InitiateAuth` and `RespondToAuthChallenge` APIs.

---

**InitiateAuth**

---

1. Create a json file, `aws-auth-data.json`

```
{
    "AuthParameters": {
        "USERNAME": "your-email@example.com",
        "PASSWORD": "your-first-password",
        "SECRET_HASH": "......(required if the app client is configured with a client secret)"
    },
    "AuthFlow": "USER_PASSWORD_AUTH",
    "ClientId": "5m........................"
}
```

2. Send a request on `https://cognito-idp.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/` (if the user pool is on `us-east-2` region) to call `InitiateAuth` API and initiate an authentication flow.

```
curl -X POST --data @aws-auth-data.json \
-H 'X-Amz-Target: AWSCognitoIdentityProviderService.InitiateAuth' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/x-amz-json-1.1' \
https://cognito-idp.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/
```

3. Then you'll get the user's tokens.

```
{
    "AuthenticationResult": {
        "AccessToken": "eyJra........",
        "ExpiresIn": 3600,
        "IdToken": "eyJra........",
        "RefreshToken": "eyJjd........",
        "TokenType": "Bearer"
    },
    "ChallengeParameters": {}
}
```

---

**RespondToAuthChallenge**

---

You may get a challenge as `InitiateAuth` response. For example, you will be asked to change password when you make a first 'InitiateAuth' attempt:

```
{
    "ChallengeName": "NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED",
    "ChallengeParameters": {
        "USER_ID_FOR_SRP": "abababab-......",
        "requiredAttributes": "[]",
        "userAttributes": "{\"email_verified\":\"true\",\"email\":\"your-email@example.com\"}"
    },
    "Session": "DNdY......"
}
```

In this case, change the password with `RespondToAuthChallenge` and you will get tokens.

```
{
    "ChallengeName": "NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED",
    "ChallengeResponses": {
        "USERNAME": "your-email@example.com",
        "NEW_PASSWORD": "your-second-password"
    },
    "ClientId": "5m........................",
    "Session": "DNdYN...(what you got in the preceding response)"
}
```

```
curl -X POST --data @aws-change-password.json \
-H 'X-Amz-Target: AWSCognitoIdentityProviderService.RespondToAuthChallenge' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/x-amz-json-1.1' \
https://cognito-idp.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/
```

See also:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_InitiateAuth.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_RespondToAuthChallenge.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-authentication-flow.html#amazon-cognito-user-pools-client-side-authentication-flow

Comment: quoting the docs, ... _the client credentials grant is typically intended to provide credentials to an application in order to authorize machine-to-machine requests._ and from the request body, there doesn't seem to be any input tying to the end user. So how is the token supposed to identify the user?

Comment: @daisura99 I said "Try Client credentials grant on TOKEN Endpoint" but I'm sorry, I had a wrong idea on your question. Let me rewrite the whole answer.

Comment: thanks! You saved my life. I did glance through this documentation before, but I thought it was just another SDK, didn't know one can actually use this API with HTTP REST

Comment: To add further, it would have been helpful if the [API Reference for Cognito](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html) had something like [CloudWatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/making-api-requests.html#CloudWatch-API-requests-using-post-method)!

Comment: @shoek : You are a life saver. I was trying to get access from 2 days but none of the documentation worked. You are Gem..