# Get Auth token from Cognito with CUSTOM_AUTH using Postman

Tags: oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito, custom-authentication

I am trying to implement Passwordless login using CUSTOM_AUTH via otp in AWS Cognito. I don't have any website we only have mobile app in place. I want to send phonenumber as username and in next session I am suppose to put password(OTP) as answer for the challenge. How to do this retrieve the token from postman

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to this question.

Approach is to use REST based authentication and I found how to go about it in this link [What is the REST (or CLI) API for logging in to Amazon Cognito user pools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37941780/what-is-the-rest-or-cli-api-for-logging-in-to-amazon-cognito-user-pools)